# Disable automatic security group naming in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When creating new environments, Beanstalk tends to pollute our security groups naming convention with random and extremely large strings like "awseb-e-nhmvcuvtjh-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1R8CUK434DLPG" that cannot be changed after.

So far we couldn't find a solution for passing custom names during the creation process. Is there a way?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'd sure love to know if it's possible. It would have to be something that could be created in a .ebextensions file, I'd think. I don't know about "pollute", but it's painful when trying to diagnose connection problems trying to figure out which insanely long string relates to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As CargoMeister suggested, you can create your own Security Group you'd like to use, then tell Elastic Beanstalk to use it by passing the SecurityGroup option ([Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbloadbalancer)). That way, you won't get the default security group with the ugly name.

Comment: Sorry, had to remove the check. Just found out that Beanstalk uses the SecurityGroup name you pass inside the options, however, it still creates a new SecurityGroup for every new environment your create. Have you found any way of disabling this behaviour? Same goes for load balancers btw.

Comment: No, they just make ugly names. If you want mite control, consider CloudFormation

Comment: Same problem with CloudFormation... However in my case, specifying a security group for the ELB seems to disable the creation of a default security group (for ELB only, I still get the default EC2 one).

Comment: Specifically, you want to set the "aws:elb:loadbalancer/SecurityGroups" and "aws:elb:loadbalancer/ManagedSecurityGroup" options.  Once I did this (and removed some customisation I was doing in ebextensions) EB stopped creating the ELB securoty group.