# Configure elastic-beanstalk loadbalancer security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to configure a security group for elastic-beanstalk loadbalancer with terraform

I tried this options where eb-ec2-security-group has inbound rule for the eb-lb-security-group source:

```
setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name      = "LoadBalancerType"
    value     = "application"
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "SecurityGroups"
    value = "${aws_security_group.eb-ec2-security-group.id}"
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:loadbalancer"
    name = "SecurityGroups"
    value = "${aws_security_group.eb-lb-security-group.id}"
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:loadbalancer"
    name = "ManagedSecurityGroup"
    value = "${aws_security_group.eb-lb-security-group.id}"
}
```

But it still creates loadbalancer that uses it's own security group. I found this question [Disable automatic security group naming in Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842260/disable-automatic-security-group-naming-in-elastic-beanstalk) but setting ManagedSecurityGroup doesn't work for me with terraform.

Comment: Do you want to use *application load balancer* or *classic load balancer*? `aws:elb:*` are used for *classic load balancer*.

Comment: I'm using application load balancer. I suppose that I had to use elbv2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing namespace to aws:elbv2:loadbalancer worked for me

```
setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
    name = "SecurityGroups"
    value = "${aws_security_group.eb-lb-security-group.id}"
}
setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:loadbalancer"
    name = "ManagedSecurityGroup"
    value = "${aws_security_group.eb-lb-security-group.id}"
}
```

And there is no need to create explicitly a security group for the ec2 instance for configuring the inboud rule for loadbalancer because it creates it automatically.